# Angular and Express routing

Tags: express, angularjs

I've been through many Angular-express seeds and kind of worked out how they work. 
The problem I am having is: **1).** I would like to use ejs-locals for templating. **2).** How to configure correctly the routing of the server-side and client-side. And also, when entering a URL such as `/about`, not to generate the error: `cannot /get`

**angular *app.js*** contains:

```
// angular stuff

$routeprovider.when('/', {
 templateUrl: 'index',
 controller: IndexCtrl
});
$routeprovider.when('/about', {
 templateUrl: 'partials/about',
 controller: IndexCtrl
});
```

**express app,js** contains:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/about', routes.about);
```

**routes folder** contains 'index.js':

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index',{name:"Hello"});
};

exports.about = function (req, res) {
  res.render('partials/about');
};
```

**Views folder** contains `index.ejs`:

```
<!--HTML head/navigation bar here-->
<div ng-view></div>
```

and inside views folder is a `partials` folder:
(**Views/partials/**)

**index.ejs:**

```
 <h1>Index</h1>
```

**about.ejs:**

```
<h1>About</h1>
```

Comment: Wow, I had pretty much this same exact question. The Angular site doesn't do a great job explaining the relationship between server-side and client-side routing with Angular. Or maybe I didn't do a great job of understanding. Regardless, your question is a really important one.

Comment: very true. I was stuck on this situation for a good day or 2 and I really dislike the jade language. kudos to the guy who gave the answer!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add these routes to your express server

```
app.get('/partials/:filename', routes.partials);
app.use(routes.index);
```

Then in `routes.js`

```
exports.partials = function(req, res){
  var filename = req.params.filename;
  if(!filename) return;  // might want to change this
  res.render("partials/" + filename );
};

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {message:"Hello!!!"});
};
```

This will make sure that express returns rendered templates when making requests to `partials/index` and `partials/about`.

Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/4277025

Comment: Thank you so much man. You don't understand how much I appreciate this.

Comment: I had to change res.render("partials/#{filename}"); to res.render("partials/" + filename);  I added a working plain javascript example here: https://github.com/andr3w321/angularjs-ejs-partials

Comment: nice catch! I missed the CoffeeScript string interpolation when doing the conversion to JS. I've updated my answer.

Comment: `app.use(routes.index);` will hide 404 errors, but this is a common pattern in Angular anyways. I've asked about this at [Angular's routing hides 404 responses for nonexistent routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715249/angulars-routing-hides-404-responses-for-nonexistent-routes).

Comment: if you add a subdirectory to group partials this will break

Comment: Should you remove the file extension from filename? I don't think you want to call res.render('partials/some-example.html'). Don't you want res.render('partials/some-example') ?

Answer (score 5):

That's how I did it. I'm using Jade, but Ejs will be similar:

**app.js**

```
// Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);
```

My templates are stored in **/views/partials**:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Clientside you can now use angular's $routeProvider to load the partials:

```
/*global define */

define([
   'angular',
   'controllers/aController',
   'controllers/bController'],
   function (angular, aController, bController) {
    'use strict';

    return angular.module('controllers', [], ['$controllerProvider', '$routeProvider',
        function ($controllerProvider, $routeProvider) {
            $controllerProvider.register('AController', ['$scope', aController]);
            $controllerProvider.register('BController', ['$scope', bController]);
            // routes
            $routeProvider.when('/A', {templateUrl: 'partials/A', controller: aController});
            $routeProvider.when('/B', {templateUrl: 'partials/B', controller: bController});
            $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/A'});
        }]);
    }
);
```

Comment: I assume `/partials/:name` just means make a route for each partial that you might have? Not that `/partials/:name` is some clever version of `*` to catch all routes inside of partials? If it is a catch all I'm struggling to use it :)

Answer (score 5):

I was having some trouble with using jade and angular, this is what worked for me.

directory structure:

```
public
  |-js
  |-css
  |-views
    |-main
      -main.jade
    |-auth
      -login.jade
server
  |-includes
    -layout.jade
  |-views
    -index.jade
server.js
```

Then in the server.js config for routing looks like:

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
})
// server side route for the partials files
app.get('/views/*', function(req, res){
    res.render('../../public/views/' + req.params);
})

// everything handled by this route
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
})
```

Then angular routes look something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/views/main/main',    // gets main.jade from server
    controller: 'mainCtrl'
})
```

My `index.jade` looks like this:

```
extends ../includes/layout

block main-content
    .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top
        div(ng-include="'/views/account/navbar-login'")
    section.content
        div(ng-view)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,

```
const path = require("path");

/* For serving static HTML files */
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

/* For ejs, jade/pug engines */
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.render(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/index.pug'));
});
```