# AngularJS routing in ExpressJS

Tags: angularjs, express

I have an AngularJS app on a NodeJS server with ExpressJS. Now I am serving an Angular app as static files:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
```

But in navigation, I have a # sign:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/queryes
```

To solve this problem, I put this code in the Angular Router:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

But now I can't get partial views. How do I mix Angular Routes with ExpressJS?

Comment: I had a similar Angular-Express routing problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860899/angular-and-express-routing. maybe this will help. not sure if you have seen it or not

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In order to use AngularJS html5mode along with Express, you must serve "index.html" for all requests to leave all routing up to AngularJS. I had this same problem a while back.

So first, you declare all API endpoint routes, any static file directories (CSS, JS, partials, etc), and then serve index.html for all remaining requests. For example:

```
    // serve all asset files from necessary directories
    app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + "/app/js"));
    app.use("/img", express.static(__dirname + "/app/img"));
    app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + "/app/css"));
    app.use("/partials", express.static(__dirname + "/app/partials"));
    app.use("/templates", express.static(__dirname + "/app/templates"));

    // any API endpoints
    app.post('/api/v1/auth/login', routes.auth.login);

    // serve index.html for all remaining routes, in order to leave routing up to angular
    app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {
        res.sendfile("index.html", { root: __dirname + "/app" });
    });
```

Comment: I also have api folder both app folder and now is conflict.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you update your original question with a code sample/error message?

Comment: I have also on my www.myapp.com/api/ my API. And this code not works for api routes.

Comment: Your API routes need to all be defined above the `app.all` call. In my example, the `app.post` is an API endpoint example.