# Page reload fails when using Angular Ui Router with Html5 mode enabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular UI Router in my angular app and i have enabled HTML5 mode to remove the # form the URL by using $locationProvider in the config.

```js
var app = angular.module('openIDC', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login', 
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
});
```

I have also set the `<base href="/" />` tag in the index.html file as well. The routing works fine and i can navigate to pages and the # is removed but when i refresh the page using the reload button on the browser there is a 404 error response.

[image]

Why is this happening and how can i fix it and have HTML5 mode enabled to have proper URLs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kasun, the reason that this is occurring is because you are trying to refresh the page from one of your sub routes (has nothing to do with ui-router).

Basically if you request `www.yourdomain.com/` you likely have your server setup to return `index.html` which bootstraps your angular app. Once the app has loaded, any further url changes take `html5Mode` into consideration and update your page via ui-router.

When you reload your page the angular app is no longer valid as it has not loaded yet, so if you are trying to load a sub route (for example: `www.yourdomain.com/someotherpage`), then your server does not know how to deal with `/someotherpage` and likely returns `404` or some other error.

What you need to do is configure your server to return your angular app for **all** routes. I primarily use node/express, so I do something like:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    // call all routes and return the index.html file here
}
```

*Note: I usually use something like this as a final catch all, however I also include other routes above it for things like requesting static files, web crawlers, and any other specific routes that need to be handled.*

Comment: That's basically the solution. One thing I'd like to add: if your backend is also serving dynamic data, e.g. an API, you want to isolate the API from this redirection, so you have to add this rule only if a file that matches the request does not exists and no other API route is matched as well.

Comment: Good point. Updated my answer. As for APIs though, I prefer to run them from a separate url/domain.

Comment: There is a good example of NodeJS serving a SPA here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396900/angularjs-routing-in-expressjs

Answer (score 9):

You need to to setup url rewrite on server side

for apache it would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html
```

in `.htaccess` file(be sure that `mod_rewrite` apache module is enabled)

and config like this for nginx:

```
location / {
    ....
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: How do you do the same thing in IIS?

Comment: Not sure, never done this in IIS. But this answer looks right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode#26152011

Answer (score 4):

Noticed a comment asking about IIS - didn't see it in here yet - but this is how I have mine working. Make sure to have URL Rewrite 2.0 installed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>`
```

Answer (score 3):

first make .htaccess file then copy past these code

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]


    RewriteRule ^ your root folder/index.html [L]
      </ifModule>


<base url="/"></base> in index.html file
```

Answer (score 2):

Cant explain in details why this happening but I can describe you a way i solved out this problem. So i used UrlRewriterFilter for my SpringMvc backend. Angular general module config :

```
var app = angular.module('ilonaChatGeneralModule', 
    [
        'ui.router'
    ]);

app.config(function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    var home = ['/', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/userlist.html'
    }];

    var login = ['login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
    }];

    var privateRoom = ['privateroom', {
        url: '/privateroom',
        templateUrl: 'views/privateroom.html'
    }];

    $stateProvider
        .state(home)
        .state(login)
        .state(privateRoom)
        ;
});
```

My home page, index.html:

```
<html ng-app="ilonaChatGeneralModule"  ng-controller="ilonaChatGeneralCtrl">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    ...

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is frontend. For backend I used UrlRewriteFilter, you can get it with following maven dependency:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
        <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've added it to my SpringMVC WebAppInitializer in next way:

```
    package com.sbk.config;

    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
    import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
    import org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter;

    import javax.servlet.*;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.util.EnumSet;

    public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {   
        private static final String URL_REWRITE_FILTER_NAME = "urlRewrite";
        private static final String URL_REWRITE_FILTER_MAPPING = "/*";

...
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            super.onStartup(servletContext);

            FilterRegistration.Dynamic urlReWrite = servletContext.addFilter(URL_REWRITE_FILTER_NAME, new UrlRewriteFilter());
            EnumSet<DispatcherType> urlReWriteDispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);
            urlReWrite.addMappingForUrlPatterns(urlReWriteDispatcherTypes, true, URL_REWRITE_FILTER_MAPPING);
        }
    }
```

This filter requires urlrewrite.xml file under ur WEB-INF directory(seems like in configurable but default place - here). Content of this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
        PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 2.6//EN"
        "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite2.6.dtd">

<urlrewrite>

    <rule>
        <from>/login$</from>
        <to>index.html</to>
    </rule>

    <rule>
        <from>/privateroom$</from>
        <to>index.html</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

I didn't read manuals carefully but i suspect that idea is when you refresh ur browser with http://yourhost:xxxx/privateroom ur app try to find physicaly existing view http://yourhost:xxxx/privateroom. But its absent. And when you redirect it to ur base page angular would built correct link to physical file using its states definition. I can mistake in theory but it works in practice

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot configure your server, configure your web.xml with the following to handle refresh while the user is on an html5 push path.

```
<error-page>
    <!-- Mapping a 404 when user refreshes with an html5 push route-->
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score -2):

the easiest way worked for me is:

use `<base href="/admin/"></base>` in index.html

I'm doing it for my admin page

Comment: The OP's problem has nothing to do with the base url. The accepted answer has already addressed the issue very well.

Comment: but how it solve my problem, if you can clear me, thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "my problem"?