# Remove # from the URL in Python Simple HTTP Server

Tags: python, angularjs, http, simplehttpserver

I have an angularjs app that uses Angular UI Router and the URL that are created have a # in them.. Eg. `http://localhost:8081/#/login`. I am using Python Simple HTTP server to run the app while developing. I need to remove the # from the URL. I know how to remove it by enabling HTML5 mode in angular. But that method has its problems and i want to remove the # from the server side.

How can i do this using Python Simple HTTP Server?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting see also https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: No its not. I know how to remove it from angularJS. but as i said, It creates  problems. I have faced it. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936224/page-reload-fails-when-using-angular-ui-router-with-html5-mode-enabled)

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't read properly. I have been struggling with this issue with Python Simple HTTP Server myself, I did not find a solution. I did however manage to do it  with NodeJS http-server.

Comment: Question is not clear. Url string is client side property and all that server can do - change the logic how to parse provided route, but not change url on the client side. Here is only one visibly for me way: generate 301 HTTP response of the server with fixed url, but there no guarantee that  angularjs will not append # again.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive from BaseHTTPRequestHandler and override the do_GET method.

```
class MyHTTPHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        # do your own processing further, if you want to pass it back to
        # default handler with the new path, just do the following
        self.path = self.path.strip('/#')
        BaseHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i had a similar problem but the difference is that i had Spring on the Server Side.

**You can capture page not found exception at your server side implementation, and redirect to the default page [route] in your app.** In Spring, we do have handlers for page not found exceptions, i guess they are available in python too.

Answer (score -3):

You could catch the string that represends the webadres adres, and if there is a # in replace it with a empty character.

```
stringA = 'http://localhost:8081/#/login'
stringB = stringA.replace("#", "")
print(stringB)
```

Comment: Yes. If you don't like my answer, well sorry. But I am just trying to help. And there are more roads to Rome. :-)

Comment: I know you are trying to help. Your answer doesn't make sense that's why i asked. I wanted to remove the # from the URL when it runs on the SimpleHTTPServer just like it can be done in IIS and Apache. I have no knowledge in python so if this is a part of a larger answer add it.

Comment: Then why did you add a python tag to it?

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer.