# AngularJS html5 mode with nodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have my NodeJS application running on port 11000 and AngularJS running on port 9000.

I am using HTML5 mode true in AngularJS and my URL's with #! and redirected to / using this mode. However, when I hit refresh, it gives 404.

I do have  in my index.html.

As per the link: [Angular ui-router pressing refresh causes 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820067/angular-ui-router-pressing-refresh-causes-404-error). Before pressing the reload/refresh, the url works fine without the hashbang. When I manually add /#!/, it gets redirected to the right path.

The problem needs to be handled server side using `app.use(*, callback)` but since the server is running on port 11000, the request never really reaches there. Am I missing out on something fundamental here? I tried putting in the star wildcard for all routes in node js but that didn't help.

Comment: You should handle the request on `9000` port i.e. on which server `angular` application is running

Comment: Of course, I have a route matching the route in ui-router. It works the first time but not on page reload.

Comment: On which development server you are using it is webpack dev server or something else

Comment: I am using grunt

Comment: if you are using `grunt-dev server` then this should be handled there

Comment: Basically, I used angular generator ; https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

Comment: @ArunRedhu: Thank you for pointing it out :) I got it working by editing grunt file.  Feel free to post your response as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154035/discussion-between-arun-redhu-and-simran-kaur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are running two separate application one is on `node server` and another is on local 'grunt-dev server'. So in single page application routing is handled on client side `js` but when you refresh for a route then initially there is no `js` loaded to handle the routing and it makes a `get` request for the same to the server but there is no handling for the same so it gives `404`. You have to do config in the `grunt-file` for handling the such routes.