# AngularJS ui-router html5mode not working on reload

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

First of all, I've tried a bunch of different solutions to fix this problem, but none of them worked for me. See links below.

#### The problem:

Currently I can't use `html5mode` with ui-router because it has a `Not Found` error. The only time it loads the page, is the first load. Each refresh or trying to access an especific `URL`, there is this error:

> The requested URL /Welcome was not found on this server.

#### My code

Currently I'm using `AngularJS 1.5.0` with `ui-router 0.2.15`. **Note:** I'm using a blank app with nothing more than 2 main states and 1 main state with a child state in an apache server.

html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <base href="/"></base>
</head>
```

.config:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

server rewrite:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

#### What I tried

I was looking in a lot of topics/Questions trying to solve this. All of them points out to 3 possible solutions:

- Use `base` tag;
- Rewrite condition on server side;
- No use of `base` tag (hard to find, but there is some);

I tried all of them, following these links (and much more):

- [Page reload fails when using Angular Ui Router with Html5 mode enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936224/page-reload-fails-when-using-angular-ui-router-with-html5-mode-enabled)
- [$location / switching between html5 and hashbang mode / link rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting)
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-my-assets-and-templates-are-not-loading

And others links.. But none of them work, always the same result. When I get a diferent error, it's this one:

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

When I try to use the rewrite rule like this:

```
<Directory />
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</Directory>
```

---

#### Edited:

After some comments, I managed to make it work, but only on the main state. When I'm on a child(nested) state, and try to refresh the page, I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
>
> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:

Example of my state:

```
.state('contact', {
    parent:'app',
    url:'/Contact',
    views: {
        'app': {
            templateUrl: 'app/contact.html',
        }
    }
})
.state('service', {
    parent:'app',
    abstract: true,
    url:'/Service',
    views: {
        'app': {
            templateUrl: 'app/service.html',
        }
    }
})
    .state('service-teste', {
        parent:'service',
        url:'/Test',
        views: {
            'service': {
                templateUrl: 'app/service_test.html',
            }
        }
    })
```

I got the error when I'm on the `service-test` state and refresh the page.

Comment: After some tests, turns out the problem isn't with the nested state itself, but with the url. @DanielBeck can you make an answer out of your comment? Because this is what solve the problem for me. At least partially. I'll make another question, since it's not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved this problem was changing some settings on the `.htaccess` file and also on the `index.html`, bu changing some paths.

*.htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

> Note that the mod_rewrite had to be enabled on my apache server. By default it was disabled.

*index.html*

I had to change the path for my css files and add a `/` at the beggining. Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/css/main.min.css">
```

I kept the other configs as usual.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //In the router config file
<base href="/"> //On the index.html just before closing the head tag
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I'm currently on a IIS server. That .htaccess rule in not work, but I think i need to write something similar in the web.config file. EDIT: found a related issue on a IIS server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode