# ui router losing data when refresh the view

Tags: angularjs

I have this route to go to news details view by passing news id using params..
its working fine .. but when i refresh the view its losing the data in the view ..

```
 .state('news', {
                url: '/news/:slug/',
                templateUrl: 'news-details.html',
                controller: 'NewsController as newsVm',
               params: {
                    id: null
                },
            })
```

i found solution by using url: '/news/:slug/:id' and remove params:{id: null}
but in this case the id will be showing in the url and my client request to remove it.

this is how im calling the route in my controller when they click on the news link

```
 $state.go('news', {id: articleId, slug: articleSlug});
```

i think this is happend because the $state.go is not refreshing the controller .. im not sure

Comment: Are you losing data which is gathered using either `slug` or `id`?

Comment: im losing the data which is gathered using id

Comment: this can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29944146

Comment: this is something different of my issue

Comment: what if you can go to previous page on reload, from where you can still visit the `news` state manually. Is that fine?

Comment: yes if i go back to previous page and click again it will go fine

Answer (score -1):

```
  .when('/news', {
                url: '/news/:slug/',
                templateUrl: 'news-details.html',
                controller: 'NewsController as newsVm',
               params: {
                    id: null
                },
            })
```