# Can angular be used within a jade template?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug

I am new to both angular and jade. I was wondering if angular can only be used with HTML, or if I could use the same angular call within a jade template? I have only seen angular templates being used with HTML, and have not found it used in any jade templates. is it possible to do such a thing? How would angular in a jade template look?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23404524/2031033

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. It would look something like:

```
body(ng-app)
    button(ng-click="yourAngularFunc()")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can download the [angular-express-bootstrap-seed](https://github.com/jimakker/angular-express-bootstrap-seed) -
A great starting point for writing AngularJS apps sauced with Twitter Bootstrap and backed by an Express-powered node.js server.
this seed contains example of using jade template

**For example:**

```
.row
    .col-lg-12
            p This is the partial for view 2.
            p
                    | Showing of 'interpolate' filter:
                    | {{ 'Current version is v%VERSION%.' | interpolate }}
```

Comment: I have an index.jade which extends a layout.jade, can I make angular calls in both jade files?

Comment: the behavior should be like a regular HTML,so as long as you have ng-app wrapper you can use angular.