# session username not showing inside angularjs ngView template but does outside of ngView

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, passport.js, ng-view

So I am able to show the username via mongoose passport-local within my successful redirect:

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('profile.html', {
        user: req.user
    });
    console.log(req.user.local.username) //correct username for the session
});
```

...and then use it to display within profile.html:

```
<p><%= user.local.username %></p>
```

...yet when trying to display the same within my ng-view:

```
<div ng-view ng-class="slide" class="slider"></div>
```

...via my route example.html template:

```
<p>welcome <%= user.local.username %></p>
```

..it is displayed as seen: not the correct username...

Is it not possible to include this information within an ngView?  Is there a solution to include this info within my template?  I have attempted to setup a factory with $http:

```
angular.module('userService', [])

.factory('Users', function($http) {
    return {
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/profile');
        }
    }
});
```

...but it was returning the entire html, so not a correct solution.

Any guidance is as always welcomed and appreciated, so thanks in advance!

**Edit in response:**
Getting the value and routing it isnt really the issue.  The issue is just getting it to display correctly within the ngView.

heres my updated code:

```
Rules.get()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.rules = data;
            console.log('Rules.get()');
            console.log(data);

            Users.get()
                .success(function (username) {
                    Users.username = username;
                    console.log('Users.get()')
                    console.log(username)
                });
        });
```

...and...

```
angular.module('userService', [])

.factory('Users', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            console.log('userService')
            return $http.get('/profile/user');
        }
    }
});
```

...which returns from:

```
app.get('/profile/user', function (req, res) {
    console.log('profile/user')
    console.log(req.user.local.username)
    res.json(req.user.local.username);

});
```

This gives me the same and correct username, but alas what do I call it to get it to display in the ngView?  If placed outside of the actual ngView div it displays fine.

From the above {{username}}  {{rules.username}} = nothing.  What should be the name of the service param within the ngView template (which I am assuming is an entirely new $scope)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here was my solution for anyone else that may be searching:

users.js:

```
angular.module('userService', [])

.factory('Users', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            console.log('userService')
            return $http.get('/profile/user');
        }
    }
});
```

route.js

```
$scope.username = {};    
.controller('cntrl', function ($scope, Users) {
        getCurrentUser(Users, $scope);
    })

        function getCurrentUser(Users, $scope) {
        Users.get()
            .success(function (username) {
                $scope.username = username.user;
            });
    }
```

service.js:

```
app.get('/profile/user', function (req, res) {
    console.log('profile/user')
    console.log(req.user.local.username)
    res.jsonp({ user:req.user.local.username});

});
```

then within html (within any ngView template):

```
<span class="username">{{username}}</span>
```

**the key being:**

```
$scope.username = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Question is possible duplicate of [Angular and Express routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860899/angular-and-express-routing)?

You could include ejs templating (like `<%= value %>`) inside ng-views (see link above), but  here are three other options.

Many people pass server data to Angular and let Angular template their views (e.g. in the MEAN stack). This would mean you wouldn't need to have ejs templating in your angular partials. Here are three ways to pass data from your server to Angular (Credit to this blog post: http://mircozeiss.com/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-from-a-server-to-angular/):

### 1. the MEAN method

The first is what is used in the MEAN stack. You could send all of the data your Angular app needs in the wrapper around your ng-view:

```
<!-- head -->
<!-- body -->
<!-- ng-view element -->

<script type="text/javascript">window.user = <%- user %>;</script>

<!-- rest of js -->
<!-- /body -->
```

This way the data can be accessed by your Angular app via a provider like so:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('UserData', [
    function() {
        return {
            user: window.user
        };
    }
]);
```

### 2. using `$http` and an api

The second is providing this data via a restful api and requesting the data via a provider using `$http` or `$resource`:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('UserData', [
    function($http) {
        $http.get('/userAPI').success(function(data){
            return data;
        });
    }
]);
```

### 3. Using ng-init

Finally you could use server-side templating inside an ng-init.

```
<div ng-init="user = <%- data %>"></div>
```

This would put the data on `$scope.user` for your Angular app to use.

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry about the misunderstanding. I can't tell where the problem is without seeing the whole app. But here's a plunker of what I think you're trying to achieve: http://plnkr.co/edit/P6MoEa?p=preview

If I had to guess I'd say `Users.username = username;` should be `$scope.username = username`.

If you're still having problems, make a plunker of what you have and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: One other thing, you said that ngView template might an entirely new $scope. Yes, if it also has a new controller. But $scopes inherit from parent $scopes so anything on a parent $scope is also accessible to the child $scope.