# Express Server, calling state.go and running a method in Controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I am currently running an express server [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) with an angular js app. I use the UI router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router with stateprovider and state.go.

I have a requirement to allow a url to be typed in the browser

```
/getEmployeeDetails/1234
```

Am i going along the right lines , in that the following code can be added to the express server.js to achieve this or should I be handling this in the angular app states.

```
app.get('/p/:empId', function(req, res) {
  controller.getEmpDetaails(req.params.empId);
  state.go("employeeDetailsview")
});
```

Comment: Why are you using ui-router inside your express server?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was the reason for writing angular code inside your Express server but you should really separate your client code from your server code.

I assume you are trying to get some employee details by ID from your server.
The way it is usually done is by sending a HTTP request with the ID number from your client to the server. Then, the server will process the HTTP request (Maybe get some data from the database) and return a HTTP response to the client. And then the client will process the response and do something with it.

In your client yo can do something like this:

```
$http.post('SERVER_URL/getEmployeeDetails/', {'id': 1234})
.then(function(response){
    // Response.data will have the data returned from the server
    // Do something with it. for example, go to other state and pass the data to it
    state.go("employeeDetailsview", {'employee': response.data});
});
```

The above will request an employee with id 1234 and do something with it.

In the server side:

```
app.post('getEmployeeDetails/', function(req, res) {
  var employeeId = req.body.id; // YOU SHOULD USE THE BODY-PARSER MODULE IN ORDER FOR THIS TO WORK. 
....
// Do something with ID
....
// Return some data to the client - for example an employee object
res.status(200).json({'data': employeeObject});

});
```

Comment: Thanks VanderVidi, but its the part 
"// Do something with ID" that I am looking for. Something along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860899/angular-and-express-routing for stateprovider

Comment: just implement there some code that gets the employee from your database.